# use ActiveSupport ``delegate to:'' to DRY presenters instance methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delegates, decorator, activesupport, presenter

I'm discovering the presenter (or decorator) pattern thanks to [Ryan Bates' tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHsq6aFlP0U) and implementing it in a training project.

I'm wondering if there's any way to use ActiveSupport `delegate` methods between custom objects ?
After refactoring my first model (Product), I'd like to use some `ProductPresenter` instance methods inside a `CartPresenter` instance. If not, maybe should I use presenter's concerns ?

I'm currently instantiating presenters inside views and accessing helpers methods by redirecting missing methods to the template, but maybe I need to instantiate presenters inside controllers (in order to have access to both `CartPresenter` & `ProductPresenter`) and define a getter for the template (so it doesn't obfuscate the `method_missing` method) ?

---

**EDIT**

Thanks to jvillian answer, `:product_presenter` now refers to a ProductPresenter instance.

As I may have other situations where I need to delegate presenters methods, I added `:delegated_presenter` to my `BasePresenter`

```rb
Class BasePresenter
  def initialize(object, template)
    @object = object
    @template = template
  end

  def self.delegated_presenter(name)
    define_method("#{name}_presenter") do
      klass = "#{name.capitalize}Presenter".constantize
      @delegator ||= klass.new(@object.send(name), @template)
    end
  end
end
```

Now inside my presenter subclasses :

```rb
class CartPresenter < BasePresenter
  delegated_presenter :product
  delegate :product_presenter_instance_method, to: :product_presenter
end
```

I'm thinking about grouping those into one BasePresenter class method that will do all the job.

This is how it's use inside a view:

```
<% present product do |product_presenter| %>
  <div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
    <%= product_presenter.display_card_image %>
    <div class="card-body">
      <%= product_presenter.display_link_to_product_name(class: 'card-title text-dark') %>
      <%= product_presenter.display_link_to_product_supplier(class: 'small text-right') %>
      <%= product_presenter.display_truncated_description(class: 'card-text') %>
      <%= render partial: 'product_buttons', locals: { product: product } %>
      <%= product_presenter.display_tags(class: 'badge badge-pill badge-secondary') %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

`present` is a helper method that returns a presenter object.

Comment: Sure, you can use `delegate` in exactly the way you're describing - that's what it is for. So, I'm not sure exactly what your question is.

Comment: `delegate :my_instance_method, to: :product_presenter` won't work, `:product_presenter` is not recognized and will fall into the `:method_missing`. Sorry if I'm not clear, what I'm looking for is to use `ProductPresenter` instance methods through a `CartPresenter` object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
delegate :my_instance_method, to: :product_presenter
```

...doesn't work because `:product_presenter` is a `symbol`, not an instance of `ProductPresenter`. Perhaps try something more like:

```
class CartPresenter

  delegate :my_instance_method, to: product_presenter 

  def product_presenter
    @product_presenter ||= ProductPresenter.new 
  end

end
```

...and...

```
class ProductPresenter

  def my_instance_method
    # do something
  end

end
```

This statement:

> I'm currently instantiating presenters inside views

...is a little concerning to me since you're creating tight coupling between the view and the presenter. It's a longer topic, but if I were generating that view you show in your code it would look something more like:

```
<% @presenter = local_assigns[:presenter] if local_assigns[:presenter] %>

<div class="card" style="width: 14rem;">
  <%= @presenter.card_content %>
</div>
```

Then, naturally, whatever presenter you pass in using `locals` needs to implement `card_content`. Now, your view knows *nothing* about `presenter` or its methods beyond that one method, `card_content`. You can do whatever you want in `card_content` and make changes in the future to `product_presenter` methods without ever having to worry about updating your view. Decoupled!

Comment: I'd to tweak it a bit to fit my context but it works perfectly. I'll edit my question to share some code. Thanks ! 
Could you elaborate on your concern ? I'll add the helper method I'm using to access a Presenter object from a view

Comment: Thanks for your edit, it really helps distinguishing views and presenters. I was considering presenters as "classes that access data from models and format it for views", but without embedding that much HTML.

Comment: Actually, my presenters never know anything about the model layer. That's left to a class called `Manager`. But, again, that's a whole other story.